# C++ equivalent of JS .charCodeAt()

Tags: c++, unicode, glib

It's probably something so extremely obvious and simple that my attempts at searching for it have failed, but: using glib you can take user input of Unicode, similar to the way I can just paste this `亜` here. I would like to be able to convert that to a string of its hex equivalent, e.g. the way `"亜".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)` returns `4e9c`. Is there such a standard function for doing that, a method with glib, or some other library that will do it?

Comment: Nothing pre-made in the C++ standard library, which is super unfortunate.

Comment: There's ICU which pretty much everyone uses though. http://site.icu-project.org/

Comment: Note that `charCodeAt` returns the first 16 bits of (the unicode value encoded as UTF-16) interpreted as a number, which is NOT always the same thing as "it's hex equivalent".  Internationalization is _very_ hard, and the first step is usually "treat text as a binary blob" and the second step is "use libraries to interact with text because it's freaking hard".

Comment: @MooingDuck Could `setLocale` be used to force standardization and then is there a specific function you know off hand that would return the value in ICU?

Comment: @Rhyono: `setLocale` won't help you because locales have very little to do with encodings.  Also, to answer the question we probably need to know what encoding the string is using, and _which_ value you're looking for.  If you want the codepoint ID, or if you want the first two bytes of the character encoded as UTF-16 like `charCodeAt` does.

Comment: @MooingDuck I was hoping for support similar to what Chrome can handle. I really don't care what it returns as long as it's unique per character and consistent across systems. Which is probably asking for more than I'll get, but it's good to know if it isn't a possibility.

Comment: @Rhyono: Note: `charCodeAt` is NOT unique per character.

Comment: Note that in JavaScript, [`String.prototype.charCodeAt` deals with UCS-2/UTF-16 code units rather than Unicode code points](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode). This means it considers supplementary Unicode symbols as a surrogate pair, and it exposes each surrogate as if it was a separate “character”. This is undesirable behavior in general. You probably want an equivalent to ES6 [`String.prototype.codePointAt`](http://mths.be/codepointat) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With glib you can get a single Unicode code point (a [`gunichar`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#gunichar)) using [`g_utf8_get_char`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-get-char).  If you need a non-zero offset, just pass the return value of [g_utf8_offset_to_pointer](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-offset-to-pointer) to `g_utf8_get_char`.  For the conversion to string, you can just use [`g_strdup_printf`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf).

So, putting it all together the translation of the code you posted would be:

```
g_strdup_printf ("%x", g_utf8_get_char (g_utf8_offset_to_pointer ("亜", 0)));
```

Comment: Note that in JavaScript, [`String.prototype.charCodeAt` deals with UCS-2/UTF-16 code units rather than Unicode code points](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode). This means it considers supplementary Unicode symbols as a surrogate pair, and it exposes each surrogate as if it was a separate “character”. This is undesirable behavior in general. The code @nemequ doesn’t seem to have this problem. TL;DR This code is not 100% equivalent to what `.charCodeAt` does, but that’s a good thing. It’s more like ES6 [`String.prototype.codePointAt`](http://mths.be/codepointat).